# VS Code Insiders - Debugging Notebook Cell

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Using version listed below. Have the experimental feature turned on, Debug button was there on the toolbar at 1 time now it's gone? Is anyone else using this feature yet?

"jupyter.experimental.debugging": true,

Version: 1.59.0-insider (user setup)
Commit: 50b3811fdc5b5c80ca516a2edfffedcbd464b033
Date: 2021-07-15T05:13:58.348Z
Electron: 13.1.6
Chrome: 91.0.4472.124
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.36-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19043

[image]

Comment: One nice thing I found recently is you can use the data viewer will debugging a .py file. Until VS code notebooks have better debugging this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I played a bit around and found out that ipykernel in version 6.2 or higher is necessary to get debugging running. I only had version 5.3.8 installed. Also I was a bit confused, because there is no debug symbol. The feature is called "Run by line". You can also have a lock at:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Setting-Up-Run-by-Line-and-Debugging-for-Notebooks
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py#_debug-a-jupyter-notebook

As a workaround I exported my notebook to a python skript. There debugging was working as usual.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).